# Is there any way that I don't use duplicate(or copy) variables for redisJSON?

Tags: javascript, redis, redisjson

Basically, I am trying to store a JSON of my application in redis using redisJSON. And I have  different functions here and there in the project where I modify and update the json. Now currently, when I tried storing and updating the values in redis, I have to continuously duplicate the values to make changes and then update it back to redis. Is there any alternative for this procedure?

```
const addUser = async () => {
  try {
    const USERS_KEY = 'users';
    let mainUsers;
    mainUsers = await redisClient.json.get(USERS_KEY, {
      path: '.',
    });

    if (!mainUsers) {
      await redisClient.json.set(USERS_KEY, '.', {});
      mainUsers = await redisClient.json.get(USERS_KEY, {
        path: '.',
      });
    }

    const mainUsersCopy = { ...mainUsers };
    console.log('The actual object we need', mainUsersCopy);

    const newUser = {
      socketId: 123,
      roomId: 456,
      teamName: teamA,
      rank: 69,
      userName: 'X'
    };

    mainUsersCopy[userName] = newUser;

    await redisClient.json.set(USERS_KEY, '.', mainUsersCopy);

    return { status: 2, userObj: mainUsersCopy[userName] };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I have given an example of above and based on that can you guys provide me a solution for not using *mainUsersCopy*. FYI, console logging the *mainUsers* we get:

```
mainUsers is here [object Object]
```

So that is why the *mainUsers* has been destructured. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to copy anything here. Just set the value within the JSON document that you want to set using `.set`:

```js
const newUser = {
  socketId: 123,
  roomId: 456,
  teamName: teamA,
  rank: 69, /* nice */
  userName: 'X'
};

await redisClient.json.set(USERS_KEY, `.${newUser.userName}`, newUser);
```

This should set the object `newUser` *within* the existing the JSON document, creating a new key in it called, in this example `X`.